# Обращение к элементам динамического массива, находящегося в классе

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы, индексы

Вот код заголовочного файла:

```
class karta
{
public:
   int c;
   int d;
   neuron **slot;
   karta(int,int);
};
```

Вот код cpp'шника:

```
karta::karta(int a,int b)
{c = a;
d = b;
neuron **slot = new neuron*[c];
    for (int count = 0; count < c; count++)
        slot[count] = new neuron[d];
}
```

После создания элемента karta в мейне (например, `karta abc(10,10);`), я хочу обращаться к нему примерно так: `abc.slot[1][1].count=1;`. (Count - это переменная типа int класса neuron(не переменная в цикле)). У меня выдает "Нарушение доступа для чтения". Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать?

Comment: класс `neuron` покажите

Comment: Заголовочный файл:


class neuron
{
public:
 int count;
 neuron();
 neuron(int);
 int F_act(neuron, int);
};
Cpp:


neuron::neuron(int a)
{
 count = a;
};
neuron::neuron()
{
 count = 0;
}
int neuron::F_act(neuron a,int x)
{
 return max(x, 0);
}
;

Comment: У вас хватило понимания для того, чтобы не переобъявить `c` и `d` локально. Зачем же вы тогда переобъявили `slot` как локальную переменную в конструкторе? Откуда у вас возникла идея написать `neuron **` перед `slot` в конструкторе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
karta::karta(int a,int b)
{ 
    c = a;
    d = b;
    neuron **slot = new neuron*[c]; 
    for (int count = 0; count < c; count++) 
       slot[count] = new neuron[d];
 }
```

Локальная переменная slot конфликтует с полем класса слот.
нужно сделать так: `slot = new neuron*[c];`

То есть вы здесь выделяете память для указателя который является локальным объектом и после выхода из конструктора `karta::karta(int a,int b)` он уничтожается(но память на которую он указывает остается брошенной!), поле `karta::slot` осталось не инициализированным